# custom module js loaded before the module which it depends, Drupal.behaviors

Tags: javascript

The "Drupal.behaviors" doesn't behave as "document.ready", if I use a document.ready I will have the correct map but if I do a Drupal.behaviors, there will be an error related to the openlayers library function which is not found :(

After check, the OpenLayers.js is loaded after my module js.
Is it possible to make it load after another one ?
I though adding a dependency on another module would make him load before the other one.

If I use a setTimeout it's working but it's not the best solution !

Do you have any idea how I can do that ?

Thank you guys

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.OL_lat_long = Drupal.OL_lat_long || {};
    Drupal.behaviors.OL_lat_long = {
         attach: function (context, settings) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var map = $('#openlayers-map').data('openlayers').openlayers;
                    var pointLayer= map.layers[1];
                    console.log(pointLayer);
                    proj4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
                    proj900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
                    Drupal.OL_lat_long.dragPoint();
                    Drupal.OL_lat_long.actualizeLatLong();
                    Drupal.OL_lat_long.clickMap();
                    $('#redrawPoint').click(function(){
                        Drupal.OL_lat_long.redrawPointOnMap();
                        Drupal.OL_lat_long.actualizeLatLong();

                    });
            },200);
        //  });
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try altering the weight of the script you add in your module?

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') .'/myscript.js', array(
    'weight' => '999',
  )
);
```

Comment: I added it in the info file, is there a way to do it to the info file instead ?

Comment: I don't think you can set weight in an .info file for a script. You can either use drupal_add_js in a module or you implement hook_js_alter and change weight on an already added script. But why go around the problem :)

Comment: yeah sure, but I was just wondering if it was possible to do it on the info file :) Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario where I needed to track site wide events through mixpanel on events like submitting a form (which will reload the page and in some times will redirect to some other page and so the minimum 300 ms time needed for mixpanel tracking was failing).

I followed this approach :

I added a cookie inside a Drupal behavior while some required event occurs using -

```
set_cookie('cookie_name', SOME_VALUE);
```

Then in the  module file under proper hook like say 'hook_node_view', 'hook_user_view', 'hook_user_login', 'hook_preprocess_page', 'hook_user_insert' or so, I added code like below :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie_name'])) {// Validation
  $value = 0;// Variable Declaration 
  $value = drupal_json_decode( $_COOKIE ['cookie_name'] );// Get value From Cookie

  if (isset($value ['via_btn'])) {// Validation
    if (!empty($value ['via_btn'])) {// Validation            
      drupal_add_js(array('YOUR_MODULE_NAME' => array('SOME_NAME' => 1)), 'setting');
    }
  }

  // Delete Cookie
  setcookie("cookie_name", '', time() - 3600);
  if (isset($_COOKIE["cookie_name"])) {
    setcookie("cookie_name", '', 1, '/');
  }
}
```

Kept the below code in theme.js (so that it's available in all pages) :

```
function set_cookie(cookie_name, cookie_val) {
  var expires = "";
  if(cookie_name && cookie_val){
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + JSON.stringify({
      via_btn:cookie_val
    })+ expires + "; path=/";
  }else{
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + "" + expires + "; path=/";
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Now added the below code in the js file :

```
Drupal.behaviors.SOME_SUITABLE_NAME = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    if(typeof Drupal.settings.YOUR_MODULE_NAME !== 'undefined' && typeof msg === 'undefined') {
      msg = Drupal.settings.YOUR_MODULE_NAME.SOME_NAME; 
      if (msg !== undefined && msg === 1) {
    // Do Something
      }
    }  
  }
};
```

So, here, what I am doing is trying to track an event after going through some proper hook so that I can skip using 'setTimeout'.

Note : In my case, I have used

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

if it worked. I went through the above approach only when default drupal behavior approach or 'document.ready' didn't work.

Hope it helps

Comment: Note that Drupal already has a cookie library in core so that you can use code like `$.cookie('my_cookie')`. You will need to add the system library yourself though where you need it. http://orga.cat/posts/jquerycookie-drupal-7